# VS2005 - Automatically requesting checkout of form on open, with "View Designer"

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2005, integration

I'm trying to integrate our Source Control(SourceAnywhere) with VS and are getting a lot of push back because of this one issue.

Almost every time we open some of our Windows forms using 'View Designer' it edits the file (* appears beside file name).  Nothing has yet been changed, I've tried comparing the before and after files and they are exactly the same.  If we have the solution bound it will check the file out, but even if its not bound it still 'edits' the file.  When you try to check the file back in, it doesn't get a new version or anything.

I've done some searching and haven't been able to find any way to change this behavior.

This is a huge pain point for me as if someone already has the form checked out and someone else tries to open it, they just get told that it can't be checked out, and the form won't open.  Or, someone who has no intention to edit the form, will now have the form checked out but hasn't made any changes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when there are controls within the form that have "Dock" set. If the IDE feels it needs to resize the form, then those controls will also be resized, and all of that information needs to get re-written to the source file. In the case where you're editing a form named "Form1" this source file is not Form1.cs, but rather Form1.Designer.cs - try comparing that file with the version from source control.

Alternatively, move to a source control system that doesn't use locking by default (for example, Subversion) or disable that feature in SourceAnywhere. This will require users to manage merge conflicts, but allows multiple users to work on a single file at the same time.

Comment: I compared all 3 of the files related to the form, all 3 are identical.  I don't think all of our developers are ready to start 'merging' code...  sad but true.